# JavaScript and php Form submission with duplicates

Tags: javascript, php, forms, duplicates

I have a duplicate form "Directors / Members". Form works just fine, meaning it adds and removes members before submission. The problem is that first submission works fine, meaning that all the variables print back to the values and the form is displayed as many times as there were members entered by a "do loop". But after the second submission, form sends only the last entered member. Seems like there is a logical errors somewhere. Can someone help me?

```
<?php $y=0; $clone =1;  do{ ?>

    <div id="<?php echo "clonedSection$clone"; ?>" class="clonedSection" >

        <p><label id="<?php echo "member_label$clone"; ?>"  >  <?php echo "Director / Member $clone"; ?></label> </p>
        <p>First name:<input type="text" name="member_firstname" id="member_firstname" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][0];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_first_name"];?></span> </p>
        <p>Last name:<input type="text" name="member_lastname" id="member_lastname" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][1];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_last_name"];?></span> </p>
        <p>Street address:<input type="text" name="member_address" id="member_address" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][2];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_address"];?></span> </p>
        <p>City: <input type="text" name="member_city" id="member_city" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][3];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_city"];?></span> </p>
        <p>State:<select name="member_state" id ="member_state">
            <?php //$states = listStates(statesList());
            foreach($states as $value){
                echo '<option >'.$value.'</option>';
            }  echo '<option selected>'.$split_members[$y][4].'</option>'; ?>
        </select> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_state"];?></span> </p>
        <p>ZIP code:<input type="text" name="member_zip" id="member_zip" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][5];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_zip"];?></span> </p>

    </div>
<?php $y++; $clone++;}while($y < count($split_members)); ?>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another member" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove member" />
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btnAdd").click(function() {

            var num = $(".clonedSection").length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newSection = $("#clonedSection" + num).clone().attr("id", "clonedSection" + newNum);

            newSection.children(":nth-child(1)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_label" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(2)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_firstname" + newNum).attr("name", "member_firstname" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(3)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_lastname" + newNum).attr("name", "member_lastname" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(4)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_address" + newNum).attr("name", "member_address" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(5)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_city" + newNum).attr("name", "member_city" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(6)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_state" + newNum).attr("name", "member_state" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(7)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_zip" + newNum).attr("name", "member_zip" + newNum);

            $(".clonedSection").last().append(newSection)

                elem = document.getElementById('member_label' + newNum);
                elem.innerHTML = "Director / Member " + newNum;

                elem = document.getElementById('member_firstname' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_lastname' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_address' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_city' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_state' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_zip' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";

            //btnDelete = document.getElementById('btnDel');
            //btnDelete.attr("disabled","");
            $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",false);

            if (newNum == 12)
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled",true);
        });

        $("#btnDel").click(function() {

            var num = $(".clonedSection").length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

            $("#clonedSection" + num).remove();     // remove the last element
            // enable the "add" button
            $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled",false);

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",true);

        });

        //$("#btnDel").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",true);
        var count = $(".clonedSection").length;
        if (count > 1)
            $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",false);
            //$("#btnDel").disabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attr in the form must be unique. Check your html, if you have `<input>`s with `name="member_address"` and not `name="member_address[x]"` where `x` is `0` to `count-1`, your form is bad.

Comment: it is unique. that java code makes it unique. right after cloning it changes all the names by adding counter to the end of the name. And when form is submitted the first time all the data for each members comes with unique names. but the second time. it submits only he last member and calls him member one

Comment: And when your php generates the form with multiple members (before the 2nd submit) is still unique? Look into your generated html before 2nd submit. Your php in the question is not generating unique names for multiple members in the form.